# rebuilding ajaxtoolkit error "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am rebuilding ajaxtoolkit code after some changes in it on VS 2008 with 3.5 framework. Wehn I build samplewebsite it give subject error. When I check in web.config line was:

**`<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4">`**

I changed targetFraework to 3.5 but still getting same error, modifed line of code is:

**`<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="3.5">`**

Please guide.